# Does ColdSpring work with MX 6?

Tags: coldfusion, coldspring, coldfusion-6

I'm embarrassed to ask such a simple question, but my searches are turning up zip. So .. does ColdSpring works with MX 6? Thanks from heat fried brain ...

Comment: Might have a better chance if you ask here: http://groups.google.com/group/coldspring-users

Comment: Any reason for still using MX 6? I mean, if you have old systems, fine, but if you're starting new development (as this question implies)...?

Comment: Just as a side note, I can understand why you may feel embarrassed by asking a question, but really you shouldn't.  We are all learning.  You should find that the CF community is rather kind and helpful.  And if anyone was to say anything negative or degrading about you asking a "simple" question then that's obviously their problem, try not to make it yours.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially yes for ColdSpring 1.0, but I would be very surprised if 2.x runs on anything less than 8.x

That said, I've just had a hunt back through my email archive and came up with a few server related bugs that might be show stoppers, but also suggestions that these issues were resolved in later releases of ColdSpring.

Not a positive yes/no I'm afraid.  It might be an element of "suck it and see".